# HashCode implementation for generic objects

Tags: java, generics, methods, hash

I've a Node class with this parameters:

```
    public class Node < T > {
      private T value;
      private int priority;
    }
```

I know that I need to override the hashcode method but I don't know how to do it because `value` is a generic object. I read that it could be done by using the address of the object, but is not recommended because the JVM can change the address of the object during the execution of the program.

Answer (score 1):

You should combine `value.hashCode()` with the `priority` value in order to calculate a `Node`'s `hashCode()`.

For example:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return 31 * value.hashCode() + priority;
}
```

This relies on users of your `Node` class overriding `hashCode()` in the relevant classes (the classes used as types of `Node` value).

Note that this is the way JDK collection classes implement `hashCode`. For example, the default implementation of `hashCode()` for `Set`s is the sum of the `hashCode()`s of the `Set`'s elements.

Comment: Is it correct using value.hashCode() even if the address of the variable could change during the execution?

Comment: @JimBelushi2 whether or not `value.hashCode()` can change during the execution has nothing to do with addresses. It has to do with the run-time type of `value` and the `hashCode()` implementation of its class.

Comment: Or to put it another way, the value of an object's default `hashCode` (aka its `identityHashCode`) never changes, even if the object's address changes.